# highlight multiple orders on channel grabber invoice

Tags: css

How do I highlight order quantities greater than 1 on a channel grabber invoice? 
Or- what is the CSS code to do this?
The invoice uses the following:

```
{{loop}}
<tr class='whitedatarow'>
<td style='border-left:solid 1px; font-size:12px;'>{{orderitem_qty[loop-count]}}</td><td style='font-size:12px;'>{{orderitem_sku[loop-count]}}</td><td style='font-size:12px;'>{{orderitem_name[loop-count]}} <br/><i>{{orderitem_variations[loop-count]}}</i></td><td id='right' style='font-size:12px;'>{{order_currency}} {{orderitem_price[loop-count]}}</td><td id='right' style='font-size:12px;'>{{order_currency}} {{orderitem_linetotal[loop-count]}}</td>
</tr>
{{loop}}
```

I want to highlight order item quantity when it is greater than 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is possible on ChannelGrabber only with HTML invoices, as opposed to PDF invoices, and can be accomplished with a little bit of JavaScript.

If you head to the invoice designer in ChannelGrabber, you could paste the following JavaScript at the end of the HTML

```
<script>

  var x=document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML;

  if(x > 1){
     document.getElementById("qty").style.backgroundColor= "blue";
  }

</script>
```

As well as doing this, you'll need to set the element ID appropriately, so that:

`<td style='border-left:solid 1px; font-size:12px;'>{{orderitem_qty[loop-count]}}</td>`

would then become:

`<td id='qty' style='border-left:solid 1px; font-size:12px;'>{{orderitem_qty[loop-count]}}</td>`

This will set the background colour of the table cell to blue, but you could specify any colour there.

If you just want to change the colour of the text itself, change `backgroundColor` to just `color`

If you'd like any more assistance, don't hesitate to get in touch via the ChannelGrabber Support email address, LiveChat or by phone.